# Video manipulation in java

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to do some video manipulation in java like resizing,format change etc.
I have searched the net and came across Xuggle. I tried to use it in my app but getting some error.So i decided to go through the basic xuggle tutorial to learn how to use it properly.But everywhere i saw in the tutorial it said to install xuggle .so i went to their web site all i found was a jar no exe.I downloaded the jar tried double clicking it, didn't work. Tried running it from command promt didn't work.So now i am stuck can't even run the basic tutorial.

I tried using Maven but when i execute the program i got this error

```
    16:55:07.304 [main] ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader - Could not load library: xuggle; version: 5; Visit http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/faq/ to find common solutions to this problem
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary0(JNILibraryLoader.java:268)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary(JNILibraryLoader.java:171)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.load(JNILibrary.java:161)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.<clinit>(FerryJNI.java:16)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.Ferry.<clinit>(Ferry.java:25)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.<clinit>(XugglerJNI.java:19)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.<clinit>(IContainer.java:1622)
    at com.video.test.GetContainerInfo.main(GetContainerInfo.java:40)
```

Can anyone help me install on my windows 7 64-bit machine or run the tutorial example using Maven?

Comment: I really don't understand why people mark someone's question a negative.If they don't like the question its there problem or at-least tell me if i have done anything wrong instead of marking it negative.Anyways i guess these are people who don't know the answers for those who know please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Xuggler 5.2, you no longer need to install it separately for each system - it comes with its own native code. So anything you see about installers is referring to the legacy system, don't worry about that.

Are you sure you're using the latest Xuggler version (5.4) with Maven? Using an earlier one that doesn't come with its own native code will cause this issue.

If you choose to go down the jar route, then you need to include that as a library in your project, not run it. I don't know what IDE you're using, but for Netbeans, you'd need to right click on the project, go to properties, select libraries from the left hand pane, then hit "add jar/folder" to add the jar file you downloaded. (You may need to add any dependencies this way also.)

Comment: Thanx,actually i am using eclipse with m2e and Xuggle 5.2.
Thanx to you i realized i was using xuggle 5.2 instead 5.4 and when i switched to 5.4 it worked fine may be it was a problem with 5.2 jar.